# Как удалить директорию при запуске скрипта npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

Перед запуском `yarn run dev` приходится удалять вручную папки, иначе вылетает ошибка при компиляции. Можно ли сделать какой-то npm скрипт и прописать его в `package.json`, который будет удалять определённые директории и все файлы внутри них?

Сейчас `package.json` выглядит так:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next-translate && next dev",
    "build": "next-translate && next build",
    "start": "next start"
  }
```

Comment: создать файл которій будет удалять и в дев дописать в начало запуск этого файла

Answer (score 2):

## работа с директориями (папками) при запуске скриптов `package.json`

Для удаления папки в ОС линукс можно воспользоваться встроенным инструментом - `rm -rf`:

```
rm -rf ./dist
```

```
rm -rf ./dist/**
```

```
"scripts": {
  "rm": "rm -rf ./dist"
}
```

### Кроссплатформенный вариант

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf

> The UNIX command `rm -rf` for node.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "rimraf":"^3.0.2",
},
"scripts": {
  "rm": "rimraf ./dist"
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "rm": "rimraf ./dist",
    "dev": "echo 'dev is started'",
    "start": "yarn rm && yarn dev"
  }
}
```

### mkdirp

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf#mkdirp

> If you need to create a directory recursively, check out [mkdirp](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp).